# Merge Sparse Data into Dictionary using Json.NET PopulateObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I would like to load sparse data in JSON format to get a result with missing data filled in with defaults, but my defaults include predefined instances of an extensible set rather than just fixed fields.

For (arbitrary) example,

Types

```
class Link
{
    public string Addr;
    public short Port;
    public Link() { Addr = "0.0.0.0"; Port = 80; }
    public override string ToString() { return Addr + ":" + Port.ToString(); }
}

class Targets
{
    public Link Fixed;
    public Dictionary<string, Link> Variable;
    public Targets()
    {
        Fixed = new Link() { Addr = "192.168.0.1" };
        Variable = new Dictionary<string, Link>
        {
            ["Common"] = new Link() { Addr = "192.168.0.2" }
        };
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var result = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        result.Append("Fixed").Append('=').Append(Fixed)
              .Append(' ');

        foreach (var link in Variable)
        {
            result.Append(link.Key).Append('=').Append(link.Value)
                  .Append(' ');
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var targets = new Targets();

string json = @"{
    'Fixed': { 'Port':12345 },
    'Variable': {
        'Common': { 'Port':12345 }
    }
}";

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, targets);

Console.WriteLine(targets);
```

Outputs `Fixed=192.168.0.1:12345 Common=0.0.0.0:12345` rather than the desired `Fixed=192.168.0.1:12345 Common=192.168.0.2:12345`.

This shows that the desired merge logic works for fixed properties, but not for items in a Dictionary despite the fact that the Dictionary will otherwise serialize/deserialize just like a type with fixed properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a while to figure this out. [Json.NET has a dedicated function for merging two JObjects together](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/MergeJson.htm). Here's your example modified to use this method:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Link
    {
        public string Addr;
        public short Port;
        public Link() { Addr = "0.0.0.0"; Port = 80; }
        public override string ToString() { return Addr + ":" + Port.ToString(); }
    }

    class Targets
    {
        public Link Fixed;

        public Dictionary<string, Link> Variable;

        public Targets()
        {
            Fixed = new Link() { Addr = "192.168.0.1" };
            Variable = new Dictionary<string, Link>
            {
                ["Common"] = new Link() { Addr = "192.168.0.2" },
                ["Common2"] = new Link() { Addr = "192.168.0.25" }
            };
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            var result = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

            result.Append("Fixed").Append('=').Append(Fixed)
                  .Append(' ');

            foreach (var link in Variable)
            {
                if (link.Key != "Variable")
                    result.Append(link.Key).Append('=').Append(link.Value)
                      .Append(' ');
            }

            return result.ToString();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var targets = new Targets();

            JObject o1 = JObject.Parse( @"{
                'Fixed': { 'Port':12345 },
                'Variable': {
                    'Common': { 'Port':12345 }
                }
            }");
            JObject o2 = JObject.FromObject(targets);
            o2.Merge(o1, new JsonMergeSettings
            {
                // union array values together to avoid duplicates
                MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union 
            });

            string json = o2.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(json);
            JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, targets);

            Console.WriteLine(targets);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
{
  "Fixed": {
    "Addr": "192.168.0.1",
    "Port": 12345
  },
  "Variable": {
    "Common": {
      "Addr": "192.168.0.2",
      "Port": 12345
    },
    "Common2": {
      "Addr": "192.168.0.25",
      "Port": 80
    }
  }
}
Fixed=192.168.0.1:12345 Common=192.168.0.2:12345 Common2=192.168.0.25:80
```

**EDIT by OP**: Refined into extension methods without extra ToString/deserialization:

```
    static class SerializerExtensions
    {
        public static T MergeObject<T>(this JsonSerializer serializer, JsonReader json, T target)
        {
            JObject o1 = JObject.FromObject(target, serializer);
            JObject o2 = serializer.Deserialize(json) as JObject;
            o1.Merge(o2, new JsonMergeSettings
            {   // union array values together to avoid duplicates
                MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union,
                // an explicit null removes an existing item
                MergeNullValueHandling = MergeNullValueHandling.Merge,
            });

            serializer.Populate(o1.CreateReader(), target);
            return target;
        }

        public static T MergeObject<T>(this JsonSerializer serializer, JsonReader json, JObject template)
        {
            JObject o1 = template.DeepClone() as JObject;
            JObject o2 = serializer.Deserialize(json) as JObject;
            o1.Merge(o2, new JsonMergeSettings
            {   // union array values together to avoid duplicates
                MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union,
                // an explicit null removes an existing item
                MergeNullValueHandling = MergeNullValueHandling.Merge,
            });

            return serializer.Deserialize<T>(o1.CreateReader());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Very nice; the intent comes through very clearly; much better than the custom JsonConverter I eventually came up with.  Refining: This requires 1 serialization, a ToString, and 2  deserializations to do the derserialization/merge, but the ToString and extra deserialization can be eliminated by replacing JsonConvert with a serializer and a CreateReader on `o2` and the FromObject could be cached and merge direction swapped if merging the same "template" repeatedly.

Comment: Correction, the `FromObject` serialization can't be entirely removed, but one could DeepClone the result if reusing the same "template" repeatedly.  I've added these refinements as an extension class and removed the unused SerializerSettings feel free to revert that second edit if you object.